# Apache clustering for windows

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, cluster

I want to setup Active-Passive apache web server cluster. Basically if one server goes down second becomes primary and vice versa. I have seen articles/videos for linux environment(like [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-active-passive-cluster-using-pacemaker-on-centos-7)) but nothing for windows servers. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: There is no difference regarding the Apache configuration between Windows and Linux.

Comment: I am very new to this, Is there any doc for active-passive cluster I can refer to

Comment: why not using active active?

Comment: windows failover cluster works in active passive fashion